# ExecutorCompletionService example code is the loop required?

Tags: java

reading JDK `ExecutorCompletionService` documentation example code

```
/*
 * Suppose instead that you would like to use the first non-null result
 * of the set of tasks, ignoring any that encounter exceptions,
 * and cancelling all other tasks when the first one is ready:
 *
 * 
 * void solve(Executor e,
 *            Collection<Callable<Result>> solvers)
 *     throws InterruptedException {
 *     CompletionService<Result> ecs
 *         = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(e);
 *     int n = solvers.size();
 *     List<Future<Result>> futures
 *         = new ArrayList<Future<Result>>(n);
 *     Result result = null;
 *     try {
 *         for (Callable<Result> s : solvers)
 *             futures.add(ecs.submit(s));
 *         for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { //??? what's the purpose for this loop? 
 *             try {
 *                 Result r = ecs.take().get();
 *                 if (r != null) {
 *                     result = r;
 *                     break;
 *                 }
 *             } catch (ExecutionException ignore) {}
 *         }
 *     }
 *     finally {
 *         for (Future<Result> f : futures)
 *             f.cancel(true);
 *     }
 *
 *     if (result != null)
 *         use(result);
 */
```

I felt this `loop` is not required, as the `take` will always block until the first `Task` Succeed, and then directly broke out there, I think the `i` when breaking out will always be zero.

is this correct? or What did I miss ?

```
 *         for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { //??? what's the purpose for this loop? 
 *             try {
 *                 Result r = ecs.take().get();
 *                 if (r != null) {
 *                     result = r;
 *                     break;
 *                 }
 *             } catch (ExecutionException ignore) {}
 *         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the comment it says that

```
* Suppose instead that you would like to use the first non-null result
 * of the set of tasks, ignoring any that encounter exceptions,
 * and cancelling all other tasks when the first one is ready:
 *
```

if the first result is null (task is completed but result is null) then it will try to get the next result

or

this for loop will jump to next element and try to get next result, if current attempt throws an ExecutionException